# What is the meaning of 'Default to Zero' that must be keep in mind in Authorization?

Tags: access-control, authorization, theory

I learned that in authorization there are some things to keep in mind, there are:

- Authorization Creep
  this happens when an employee switch roles and the previous authorization isnt removed.
- Default to Zero
- Need to Know Principle
  to limit information to someone that not need to know of the information
- Access Control List
  is a list of permissions attached to an object. An ACL specifies which users or system processes are granted access to objects, as well as what operations are allowed on given objects.

I have tried to search what "Default to Zero" means on this, but I can't find it. What does default to zero in this context mean?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be "default to zero privileges, unless proven otherwise".

E.g. writing code like:

```
access_flags = NONE
if password_match:
    access_flags.add(ACCESS_USER)
```

Instead of:

```
access_flags = ACCESS_ADMIN + ACCESS_USER
if not password_match:
    access_flags.remove(ACCESS_USER)
```

Reason being that it's easier to make (and exploit) mistakes in latter code. In the above example, latter code would still leave ADMIN privileges if passwords don't match.

Comment: could you please explain to me the differences of !password_match() and password_match, access_flags |= ACCESS_USER and &= !ACCESS_USER?

Comment: rewritten pseudo code to be more english-like. clearer?

Comment: oh, then that means before adding new access, we set the flags to zero first like on the first pseudo code?

Comment: I interpret it to start with zero access/privileges/permissions, and then add the appropriate on authentication.